# draw rectangle under stackview

Tags: layout, xamarin.ios, cgrect

I find myself in the situation of having to manually draw a rectangle with rounded edges as a background for a horizontal stack view. To create the classic ios "bubble" effect, such as whatsapp chats, where the text is surrounded by a green shape.

I am attaching the code:

```
var BackgroundStack = new UIView();
BackgroundStack.Frame = new CGRect(0, -20, TopSchedaStack.Bounds.Width, 
TopSchedaStack.Layer.Bounds.Height+40);
BackgroundStack.BackgroundColor = UIColor.TertiarySystemGroupedBackgroundColor;
BackgroundStack.Layer.CornerRadius = 20;
TopSchedaStack.InsertSubview(BackgroundStack, 0);
```

the perplexity lies in "BackgroundStack.Frame ...", I need to wrap the generated element in the "TopSchedaStack" storyboard of the UIHorizontalStackView type, with a gray rectangle. So I create it with the CGRect function but when I have to position it precisely under the object it is horizontally and vertically constrained to the view and centered. I am struggling, I cannot get the width I expect from the stack. In the storyboard file it is positioned one way but when I go to recover its width with:

```
TopSchedaStack.Bounds.Width or TopSchedaStack.Frame.Width
```

The value obtained is not what I expect. I expect the stack to be long from the left edge to the right edge of the view, taking away the guidelines. therefore it is an object constrained to the right and left respectively at point 0.

[image]
[image]

I would like the gray rectangle to cover the portion of the blue rectangle depicted in the image containing the storyaboard project. I'm pretty much going randomly changing values until it comes back, I'm sure I'll succeed sooner or later but I'm convinced it's not the right way to do this. Can you help me?

Comment: Your constrains are right.  Does it work if you `remove the BackgroundStack.Frame=...` in code behind? You can also try to set the width by `screenwidth - padding*2`.

Comment: what does it do "padding*2 "? And what it's represent?

Comment: The white space between TopSchedaStack  and screen side.